# How to convert DateTime to Date, hh-mm

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning

I wrote soql and retrieved  DateTime.
ie) '2018-11-21T10:51:12.421Z'

I would like to split Date, hours:mins like '21-11-2018 10:51'. i tried like below,

```
String value = '2018-11-21T10:51:12.421Z';

String[] dateAndTime = value.split('T');
String[] dateParts = dateAndTime[0].split('-');

system.debug('dt---'+date.newinstance(Integer.valueOf(dateParts[0]), Integer.valueOf(dateParts[1]),Integer.valueOf(dateParts[2])));
```

O/P : 2018-11-21 00:00:00

Iam expecting '21-11-2018 10:51' . dont know why hh:mm showing 00:00

Answer (score 1):

While there are certainly exceptions, it's usually best to rely on Apex to handle Date and Date-Time formatting. The [`DateTime.format()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) method will return a `String` that's converted to the local date time and locale format of the context user.

In this case, you have two separate issues.

1. Your code extracts the Date value, which is `dateAndTime[0]`, but does nothing with the Time value, which is `dateAndTime[1]`. Your code is creating a `Date`, which inherently has no time value associated with it.
2. You are looking at a version of the `Date` as printed by `System.debug()`, which formats `Date` values as if they have a time value of midnight. That's where the `00:00:00` comes from.

Comment: HI @David Reed , thanks for your response. do you have any sample in apex to handle this situation?

Comment: I can't write the code for you, Raja, and I don't really know what your objective is. I would recommend you read through the documentation on the `format()` method and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi @David Reed, yes i read the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm .. found solutions. Thanks.

Comment: HI @David Reed,  String val = '2018-11-21T10:51:12.421Z'; 

DateTime date1 = (DateTime)Json.deserialize('"'+val+'"', DateTime.class);
System.debug('oooo'+date1.format()); working as expected..